# Count certain aspect of an array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a webapp about TV Shows, to learn AngularJS. Part of it is unwatched episodes. I want to display the number in the title bar. However, what I get from Laravel is an array of objects of all episodes in the last week. For the number in the title bar to be accurate, I need to filter it. This is the controller part for this:

```
$http.get('/episodes').success(function(data) {

    $scope.episodes = data; 

    console.log(data);

    $rootScope.numberForTitle = '(' + data.length + ')';

});
```

And this is what it logs in the console:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
    created_at: "2014-09-27 10:54:10"
    id: "8"
    name: "Boardwalk Empire"
    seen: "1"
    episode: "0503"
    userid: "1"
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    created_at: "2014-09-27 10:49:41"
    id: "7"
    name: "Modern Family"
    seen: "0"
    episode: "0601"
    userid: "1"
    __proto__: Object
2: Object
    created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    id: "6"
    name: "Sons of Anarchy"
    seen: "1"
    episode: "0701"
    userid: "1"
    __proto__: Object
3: Object
    created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    id: "5"
    name: "The Big Bang Theory"
    seen: "0"
    episode: "0801"
    userid: "1"
```

How can I filter this by `seen` or at least have `$rootScope.numberForTitle` display the correct length of unseen shows?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple loop for removing seen ones? Or not even selecting the seen episodes on the server side?

Comment: Well, I need the seen ones as well for other parts of the app. However, how would a loop for removing seen ones look?

Comment: The most basic loop, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop all the episodes and pick only the unseen ones:

```
$scope.episodes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].seen != "1") {
        $scope.episodes.push(data[i]);
    }
}

$rootScope.numberForTitle = '(' + $scope.episodes.length + ')';
```

You didn't specify what you're doing with it afterwards (how are you presenting it), but it might be possible just to add a filter to an ng-repeat directive, for example.

Comment: Why do not use the $filter service? [...] You can filter your data using this, then count the result.
In addition, it is mostly not a good idea to use $rootScope instead of a controller own $scope. You still can declare a controller to expose datas to the scope, a service to provide them, and eventually to manipulate them (filtering, counting filtered results..)

Comment: @Nico, not sure it the comment is for me or for OP. But, $filter service is working on plain JS, like any other Angular component. $rootScope was introduced by OP in the original question, I just kept it.

Comment: Right, I was trying to complete your answer ($filter) and expose the $rootScope ugly concept to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep seen as well then push these objects into another array:

```
//This will keep filtered data
$scope.unseen = []; 
$scope.episodes.forEach(function(elem) {
  if (elem.seen !== 1) {
    $scope.unseen.push(elem);
  }
});
```